# How to call an external URL from a react express node component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, keycloak

I'm trying to create a login application that passes a JWT in the headers of another application.

I started from this application [User authentication keycloak 2](https://scalac.io/user-authentication-keycloak-2/) adapted to my Kecloak installation and it works fine.
Now I need to create a component that call an external URL passing the authorization token

In this component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class callUrl1 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { response: null };
  }

  authorizationHeader() {
    if(!this.props.keycloak) return {};
    return {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.props.keycloak.token
      }
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("callUrl1 called")
  }

}

export default callUrl1;
```

I need something that call an external URL; something like:

```
SOME_FUNCTION('https://www.h.net/users', this.authorizationHeader())
```

to put inside handleClick.

All that I tried gives compilation errors.

How can I go from "http://localhost:3000" to "https://www.h.net/users" passing the JWT?

Answer (score 1):

The built in library for making requests in frontend JS is called Fetch.  Here's an example of how you might do it in your case:

```js
handleClick = () => {
  fetch('https://www.h.net/users', this.authorizationHeader())
    .then((response) => {
       // do something with the response here...
    });
}
```

or with async/await:

```js
handleClick = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.h.net/users', this.authorizationHeader());
  // do something with response like:
  const data = await response.json();
}
```

For more information on Fetch, check out mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I want to go to the external page, not to fetch the page and render in node app. Something like create in the frontend app link to the external page that contain also the authorization token for the user to click.